# What is "in the context of others..." in this quote?

Tags: grammar, semantics, syntactic-analysis

The quote in question:

> the use of self-directed actions so as to choose goals and to select, enact, and
>   sustain actions across time toward those goals usually in the context of others
>   often relying on social and cultural means for the maximization of one’s
>   longer-term welfare as the person defines that to be. (Barkley, 2012, p. 176)

I'm struggling to parse this. My guesses:

- The actions are in the context of other actions relying on social and cultural means
- The goals are in the context of other goals relying on social and cultural means
- Other people (others) rely on social and cultural means?

It seems like just including a comma in a few different places could change the meaning, such as:

> the use of self-directed actions so as to choose goals and to select, enact, and
>   sustain actions across time toward those goals usually in the context of others,
>   often relying on social and cultural means for the maximization of one’s
>   longer-term welfare as the person defines that to be.

Seems to me to mean that it's the self-directed actions that rely on social cultural means (not the sustained actions, or goals)

Comment: Anyone would struggle to parse it!  The kindest thing I could say is that the author who wrote this book desperately needs an editor.

Comment: There is close to 50 words in this noun phrase :) That's the biggest I've seen in a while.

Comment: You can use ***logic / pragmatics*** to decide the intended referent of "others" (people?, actions?, goals?), but so far as the ***syntax*** is concerned it's ambiguous. Which I think makes this question Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: When I taught high school English this paragraph would get a big red circle around it and an "R" for rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to parse, and I can't be sure what was intended. But *others* nearly always means "other people" rather than "other (something else)s". If the writer had meant *other goals* I think he would have written that.